# if statements that also use .include? and && in ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, operators

I am new to Ruby and trying to create a small Zork like game.  I'm having trouble with the following lines of code:

```
puts "Do an action"
action = gets.chomp

if action.include? 'look' && 'bed'
puts "you look at the bed"
elsif action.include? 'pickup' && 'bed'
puts "you pickup the bed"
else
puts "you do nothing"
end
```

For some reason when I first type this by itself in a new file it will work.  If i change the code in anyway it will only give me the first puts.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what is/is not working? Adding the input, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior would be helpful.

Comment: If you need to check membership of multiple values to an array, you need to write it separately like `action.include?('look') && action.include?('bed')` or smarter `['look', 'bed'].all? {|o| action.include? o}` or more wicked `['look', 'bed'].all? &action.method(:include?)`

Answer (score 0):

You could monkey patch `String` to do something like this

```
class String
  def include_all?(*args)
    args.map{|arg| self.include?(arg)}.reduce(:&)
  end
end
```

Then call like

```
action = "look a dog bed for sale"
action.include_all?("look","bed")
#=> true
action.include_all?("look","bed","fish")
#=> false
```

What this does is it takes as many arguments as you supply and places them into an `Array` using the splat `*` then checks to see that each one is included in the `String`. It then reduces them to a single value using the `&` operator so it translates to

```
action = "look a dog bed for sale"
action.include_all?("look","bed")
  #args = ["look","bed"]
  #args.map{|arg| action.include?(arg)}
  #=> [true,true]
  #true & true
  #=> true
action.include_all?("look","bed", "fish")
  #args = ["look","bed","fish"]
  #args.map{|arg| action.include?(arg)}
  #=> [true,true,false]
  #true & true & false
  #=> false
```

**The other suggestions are far more standard procedure. I just like to point out to new rubyists that altering a class is a fairly simple procedure. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**

Comment: eww.           just ewww.   Let's not suggest monkey patching to someone just starting ruby.